# How can I segment/split a file in NiFi getting the small pieces?

Tags: apache-nifi

Good night

I got 5 files

```
[azureuser@ibpoccloudera output]$ pwd
/home/azureuser/logs_auditoria/output
[azureuser@ibpoccloudera output]$ ls -lrth
total 5.1G
-rw-r--r-- 1 nifi nifi 1.2G Oct  6 00:38 auditoria_20200928.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 nifi nifi 433M Oct  6 00:38 auditoria_20200927.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 nifi nifi 1.5G Oct  6 00:38 auditoria_20200929.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 nifi nifi 1.6G Oct  6 00:38 auditoria_20200925.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 nifi nifi 427M Oct  6 00:38 auditoria_20200926.txt
```

And I want to split them in smaller pieces and put it in another directory using NiFi. I use this processor secuence:

Getfile -> SegmentContent -> Putfile

**GetFile**

[image]

**SegmentContent**

[image]

**PutFile**

[image]

But when I check my output directory (PutFile) I got the last segment that gave me the SegmentContent.

There are any option to get something like linux split

```
[azureuser@ibpoccloudera output]$ split -b 524288000 auditoria_20200929.txt auditoria_20200929

[azureuser@ibpoccloudera output]$ ls -lrth
total 6.5G
-rw-r--r-- 1 nifi      nifi      1.2G Oct  6 00:38 auditoria_20200928.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 nifi      nifi      433M Oct  6 00:38 auditoria_20200927.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 nifi      nifi      1.5G Oct  6 00:38 auditoria_20200929.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 nifi      nifi      1.6G Oct  6 00:38 auditoria_20200925.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 nifi      nifi      427M Oct  6 00:38 auditoria_20200926.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 azureuser azureuser 500M Oct  6 00:54 auditoria_20200929aa
-rw-rw-r-- 1 azureuser azureuser 500M Oct  6 00:55 auditoria_20200929ab
-rw-rw-r-- 1 azureuser azureuser 500M Oct  6 00:55 auditoria_20200929ac
-rw-rw-r-- 1 azureuser azureuser  14M Oct  6 00:55 auditoria_20200929ad
```

Comment: Did you autoterminate the "original" output from the segmentContent processor?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using a SplitText and UpdateAttribute.

I use SplitText because I have a json file so, if I use SegmentContent, sometimes y cut one record and get errors.

and with UpdateAttribute, I change the name of the file by UUID, so I am pretty sure that I don't have any repeated records.

**SplitText**

[image]

**UpgradeAttribute**

[image]